# netbeans 7.2.1 with mysql connection java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, netbeans, java.lang.class

i am working on servlet and when i run the servlet i got error in explorer which says

```
type Exception report

message
descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1397: Wrapper cannot find servlet class com.jp.NewServlet or a class it depends on
root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jp.NewServlet
```

the following is the code of the program which is itself is build under netbeans

```
package com.jp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet NewServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}
}
```

the following error is shown on netbeans under glassfish server message

```
SEVERE: WebModule[/JP first-war]Error loading WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/) com.jp.loginservlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jp.NewServlet
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServletClass(StandardWrapper.java:1403)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

i think the below is also imp error

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[loginservlet]: PWC1382: Allocate exception for servlet NewServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jp.NewServlet
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServletClass(StandardWrapper.java:1403)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

i have properly set web.xml file for servet mapping and all..
the thing is that when i type package and when the hint shows for it i cant find my package path which is com.jp

can u guide me out of this..?
its urgent

thanking u in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full name of your NewServlet class is com.jp.NewServlet. The server however is searching for a class named com.jp.loginservlet.

In your web.xml, is there the Tag:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jp.loginservlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

should be

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.jp.NewServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

edit: 
just in case: did you try "Clean and Build"? In most cases that solves the problem.

Comment: yes...but i have just posted the wrong error.it was the error of other page and yes thank u the error is solved by using clean and build.